# How to retrieve a column field to use in actionParams when using a format action in JSON - MS FLOW

Tags: flow, json-formatting

I'm working on have to trigger ms flow from a link in sharepoint via the modern UI list.
I can trigger the link and it fires the flow but instead of hardcoding the flow GUID i want to store them in a field in SharePoint and pass it in as an action parameter in the JSON.
Is this possible? See screenshot below of the JSON for custome formating

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
    "color": "#0078d7"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Flow"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "style": {
        "border": "none",
        "background-color": "transparent",
        "color": "#0078d7",
        "cursor": "pointer"
      },
      "txtContent": "Start Flow",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "executeFlow",
        //How can i pass a column field name here to the ID instead of the hardocded GUID(instead the GUI will be coming from a SharePoint list?)

        "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"c42f9124-653d-468a-8178-07063e5f5c88\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```